# Unable to open database file in flask python msqlite3. OS is windows 7

Tags: python, database, windows, flask

I'm trying to connect a database to my register.html page. But i get the error that it cannot open the database file.

Here is my code:

In the dbconnect.py file

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_file =    'c:\gebruikers\zenner\desktop\databases\pythonprogramming.db'

def connection():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pythonprogramming.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    return c, conn
```

in the **init**.py file

from dbconnect import connection

```
@app.route('/register/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def register_page():
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        return("okay")
    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

What causes this problem? I tried adjusting my security settings without any luck.

Comment: Please post the actual error message you are getting. Also I assume you have included `from dbconnect import connection`

Comment: In the browser I'm getting a string : "unable to open database file" . Getting no error in the terminal. I'm also using pycharm to run my website in google chrome. And yes i have that import in the __init__.py file